# Need to locate code of video from the page source and also, how to make the video playable

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

I have a requirement where I need to embed the video code directly in a blog.

I was able to figure out the code where the video is there, I stored it in a html file,named it as video.html

This is the link from where I have to extract the video, Watch Video link:

```
http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/stocks-views/hdil-tata-global-ifci-top-picks-manoj-vayalar_925072.html
```

The problem is that when I upload video.html file, only the static image gets loaded. I need the video to be playable when I click the button, so that I can directly insert this video.html in the blog.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="CL"></div>
<div class="vidnewsin">
<div class="vidmd">
<div class="vidplayin">
<div class="gD_18"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:load_vplayer('925072');" title="Watch Video" ><span class="vidtg"></span><strong>Watch Video</strong></a></div><div class="MT10"></div>
<div id="load_player">
<div class="PRVEDO"><a class="playBtnSn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:load_vplayer('925072');"></a><img src="http://img.moneycontrol.co.in/news_image_files/vid_img/2013/07/925072.jpg" width="441" height="361" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="http://img.moneycontrol.co.in/images/news/vplrBar.gif" alt="" /></div>
                                         <div class="PT10">
```

I know that I am loading only the image source, hence the video is getting loaded as an image.

Also, how to directly insert the video.html in the blog.

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks.

**Updated:**

Is it possible to load video through the html file which I am creating? I mean, if I can extract the content server of the video, then, will the video be playable through an html file? Thanks.

**Updated:**

I have modified the code a bit, and directly added the video url:

```
<div class="CL"></div>
<div class="vidnewsin">
<div class="vidmd">
<div class="vidplayin">
<div class="gD_18"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:load_vplayer('http://videos.moneycontrol.com/web18/mc-vods/2013Jul/manoj_variuousstocks_25jul.mp4');" title="Watch Video" ><span class="vidtg"></span><strong>Watch Video</strong></a></div><div class="MT10"></div>
<div id="load_player">
<div class="PRVEDO"><a class="playBtnSn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:load_vplayer('http://videos.moneycontrol.com/web18/mc-vods/2013Jul/manoj_variuousstocks_25jul.mp4');"></a><img src="http://img.moneycontrol.co.in/news_image_files/vid_img/2013/07/925072.jpg" width="441" height="361" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="http://img.moneycontrol.co.in/images/news/vplrBar.gif" alt="" /></div>
                                         <div class="PT10">
```

I thought that by doing this, the video will be playable, directly with an HTML file, which late, I will use in the blog.

But still, the issue is not resolved.

Kindly let me know where am I wrong, even if this means, refactoring the ajax request from the moneycontrol page, though I have no idea on Ajax scripting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the source HTML of the page, I found that when the play button clicked, there will be a ajax request to get the **real** video embed code. In your case, this code is

```
<div style="z-index:0;" id="player">
  <embed width="468" height="351" flashvars="servicetype=chunk&amp;streamurl=2013Jul/manoj_variuousstocks_25jul.mp4&amp;totalchunk=4&amp;videopart=&amp;server=http://videos.moneycontrol.com/web18/mc-vods/&amp;controllerpath=http://img.moneycontrol.co.in/tv/flash/control_moneycontrol_chunk_24July.swf&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showrelatedbutton=0&amp;relatedPath=http://api.moneycontrol.com/solr/solr_related_videos_multiple_test.php?id=925072%26format=player&amp;site=www.moneycontrol.com&amp;trackingurl=http://vtracking.in.com/TackImg_CHK_VOD.PNG&amp;googlepreroll=0&amp;googlepostroll=0&amp;googleoverlay=0&amp;channelindex=3&amp;vastpreurl=http%3A%2F%2Fc7.zedo.com%2Fjsc%2Fc1%2Ffns.vast%3Fn%3D1656%26c%3D1211%26d%3D18%26s%3D11%26v%3Dvast2%26z%3D&amp;vastposturl=http%3A%2F%2Fc7.zedo.com%2Fjsc%2Fc1%2Ffns.vast%3Fn%3D1656%26c%3D1214%26d%3D18%26s%3D11%26v%3Dvast2%26z%3D&amp;vastoverlayurl=http%3A%2F%2Fc7.zedo.com%2Fjsc%2Fc1%2Ffns.vast%3Fn%3D1656%26c%3D1213%26d%3D83%26s%3D11%26v%3Dvast2%26z%3D" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" name="videoPlayer" id="videoPlayer" style="undefined" src="http://img.moneycontrol.co.in/tv/flash/Main_chunk_24July.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</div>
```

For more details ,the ajax request handler is located at http://www.moneycontrol.com/mccode/news/article/load_video_ajax.php`. You can see it in the javascript

```
function load_vplayer(auto_num)
{
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null)
  {
    window.location="http://www.moneycontrol.com/tablet/index.php?v_autono="+auto_num;
  }
  else
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/mccode/news/article/load_video_ajax.php",
      data: {auto_num:auto_num},
      timeout:5000,
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {},
      success: function(data){
        if(data!='')
        {
          $("#load_player").html("");
          $("#load_player").html(data);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Another problem is the `flashvar` property which locating the video location. As you can see in the embed code, the flash player use relative url as input. Therefore, I afraid that you can not embed video from this site just by using its own HTML.

**Updated**

In the ajax respond, the video uri is located in two segment:

- The server `server=http://videos.moneycontrol.com/web18/mc-vods/`
- The video relative url `streamurl=2013Jul/manoj_variuousstocks_25jul.mp4`

With the above data, the full url of the video is `http://videos.moneycontrol.com/web18/mc-vods/2013Jul/manoj_variuousstocks_25jul.mp4`. You can use it with another player [as in my demo](http://jsbin.com/evunep/1/) to load the video.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am storing the video in my own html, named video.html. Is it possible to load the video this way? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are still load video to your HTML, all things to do is extracting the video url from the `data` of ajax respond and use it with your **own** flash player (not the one used in the source website).

Comment: I have update my answer with an demo with another flash video player and some information about video url extracting, hope this help you.

Comment: I could not find the reference of the flashvar in the html code, also, is not this possible to add functionality to the button in the .html file, where I have placed the code. But content will be an issue.

Comment: The `flashvar` is in the responded ajax, you should request to the ajax handler first.

Comment: Do I need to write this http://videos.moneycontrol.com/web18/mc-vods/2013Jul/manoj_variuousstocks_25jul.mp4 in the onclick:javascript('') function? Thanks.

Comment: I used the code which you had provided, now it is working, thanks, but, I want the edit in JS and also, the button to be removed. Is this possible? Thanks :).

Comment: Also, if I am able to load the video throught the html file, then, in the blog, I can directly insert the html right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can remove the button, just call the `load_video` in your script. About the blog, if the blog provider support javascript, you can freely use this code.